# Manage docker container from angular project using dockerode

Tags: angular, docker

I have an angular project and I would like to inspect a docker container after a button click.
So I have set up my onclick function like this:

```
onSubmit() {
   const docker = new Dockerode({socketPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'});
   var container = docker.getContainer('97bfae66b11f');
   container.inspect(function (err, data) {
   console.log(data);
 });
}
```

But when I click the button I get an error:

`http://localhost:4200/containers/97bfae66b11f/json 404 (Not Found)`

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Does this Dockerode run on the browser? There is nothing about this in the readme (https://github.com/apocas/dockerode), it seems to be nodejs only.

Comment: Which means I need a server to communicate with Docker?

Comment: I really have very low knowledge about Docker, but it seems so...

Comment: Kind of makes sense, because I don't think that for security reasons browsers could communicate with sockets..

Comment: Yeah, seems you would need to set up a (node) service with Dockerode and then you could access that service via your Angular app.